# Не запускается pyspark в PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyspark

Начинаю изучать pysaprk. Для этого установил Hadoop, а затем в PyCharm через pip поставил pyspark, однако он не запускается и выдаёт странную ошибку:

```
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
```

Пробовал установку переменных PYTHONPATH и SPARK_HOME - не помогло, результат тот же.

Запускаемый код:

```
import pyspark
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('hhh').setMaster('local[1]')
Sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправить отображение ошибки удалось, установив кодировку системы, совместимую с UTF-8, после чего она приобрела вид: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

В итоге, порывшись на форумах, я обнаружил, что pyspark, который ставится через pip подходит для работы на уже существующих кластерах, однако не содержит в себе полной функциональности spark'a.